# Cannot lookup a consumer from a connection that had not been registered / The subscription does not exist

Tags: java, queue, activemq-classic, broker

I run an ActiveMQ 5.5.1 broker with two queue. Clients produce messages (varying from many small to some of significant size) and put them into queue 1, from where consumers take the messages from the queue by pulling them at their speed (message prefetch = 0). Messages are sent in transactions. Consumers then calculate some stuff and put an answer message into queue 2 when they have finished their calculation. Clients take the answer message from this queue.

Persistence is through kahaDB. Producer flow control is enabled, but the memory limits are not hit.

This works alright and throughput does not seem to be an issue either.


However I see the following two exceptions on the broker sometimes. Could anyone give me a hint what they might mean? I could not find anything useful in the ActiveMQ docs or Google either.

Many thanks,
jayeff

```
 WARN [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///140.39.12.159:40323] (TransportConnection.java:290) - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service Async error occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The subscr
iption does not exist: ID:XYZ:28807:2:1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The subscription does not exist: ID:XYZ:28807:2:1
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.messagePull(AbstractRegion.java:389)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.messagePull(RegionBroker.java:557)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.messagePull(BrokerFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.messagePull(BrokerFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.messagePull(BrokerFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.messagePull(MutableBrokerFilter.java:245)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessagePull(TransportConnection.java:470)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.MessagePull.visit(MessagePull.java:43)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:306)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:179)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onCommand(TransportFilter.java:69)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.onCommand(InactivityMonitor.java:227)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:220)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:202)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

and

```
 WARN [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///140.39.12.159:45179] (TransportConnection.java:290) - org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Service Async error occurred: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot lookup a consumer from a connection that had not been registered: ID:XYZ:31449
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot lookup a consumer from a connection that had not been registered: ID:XYZ:31449
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.SingleTransportConnectionStateRegister.lookupConnectionState(SingleTransportConnectionStateRegister.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.lookupConnectionState(TransportConnection.java:1423)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessagePull(TransportConnection.java:470)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.MessagePull.visit(MessagePull.java:43)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:306)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:179)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onCommand(TransportFilter.java:69)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor.onCommand(InactivityMonitor.java:227)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:220)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:202)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I'm struggling to figure out the "Cannot lookup a consumer" warning. Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Sorry, we never really found the reason behind this issue. However we switched from TCP to NIO as wireformat and are running 5.8.0 by now and didn't observe the warning anymore. Maybe that's an option for you too.

Comment: We are running 5.9 activemq and still see the issue. Might be the TCP. Thanks for the follow up.